# How to compare value with list item and click on the desired element using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have 18 names in a list and want to click on the name after comparision with an another element.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='w-100 f7 pv2 ph1 mb2 bg-white-20 pointer']// following :: span[@class='v-mid']"));
    Iterator<WebElement> att = list.iterator();
    WebElement e;
    while(att.hasNext()) {
        e= att.next();
                if(e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Rohit Sharma"));
                {
                    e.click();
                    break;
                }
```

Below is the inner HTML Code

```
<div class="w-50 dib">
<img class="dib w2 h2 br-100 bg-dirty-green mr1 v-mid" 
src="https://fanfight.com/images/player.png" alt="">
<span class="v-mid">Saurabh Tiwary</span>  // i am taking this in my list and want to compare with a another name if both match it will select 
 </div>
 <div class="dib tc ttu" style="width: 15%;">MI</div>
   <div class="dib tc" style="width: 15%;">0</div>
 <div class="dib tc" style="width: 15%;">7.2</div>
 <div class="dib tc" style="width: 5%;"></div>
```

> Like the above HTML code i have 18 div's

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a *List* you can easily iterate over the *List* items and invoke `click()` to your matched condition as follows :

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='w-50 dib']//span[@class='v-mid']"));
for(WebElement ele:list)
    if(ele.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Rohit Sharma"));
    {
        e.click();
        break;
    }
```

**Note** : While invoking `findElements()` I have constructed the *Locator Strategy* with the elements present in the HTML you have provided which you may suffice to your needs or else you may require to change the *Locator Strategy* accordingly.